# Need just one trigger on Hierarchical Data table update on sql server instead of trigger on row update. Is ther any way to do?

Tags: sql-server, database, hierarchical-data, database-trigger

I have Hierarchical Data table and I need to maintain a replica of it in other DB for the people with less access rights to use.
Now this Hierarchical Data table is using Sql server heirarchyid and function to get the tree, sub tree. Any movement in tree cause the entire subtree below of that node to update Db in all those nodes row.

Now to maintain a sync I can create trigger on update to update the replica table but it will fire n updates if the tree with size n gets moved.

Is there any way I can do this is one trigger for moving node and auto update the children?

Comment: Sure it is possible. But you didn't provide any details that would let somebody help you write it. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks Sean for the link. I will remember for next time.

Comment: If you want help you might consider using the ideas found at that link this time.